# What is the backend_overridable service tag usable for?

Tags: 9, symfony-services

On some core services, I see they have a tag of `backend_overridable`. I see this changelog, but is there an example?

https://www.drupal.org/node/2306083

Is that essentially what something like Memcache is doing?

```
$settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.memcache';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example:

*views/views.services.yml*

```
  views.date_sql:
    class: Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\MysqlDateSql
    arguments: ['@database']
    tags:
      - { name: backend_overridable }
  pgsql.views.date_sql:
    class: Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\PostgresqlDateSql
    arguments: ['@database']
    public: false
  sqlite.views.date_sql:
    class: Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\SqliteDateSql
    arguments: ['@database']
    public: false
```

Which makes it possible to query dates differently depending on the default backend.

Cache bins can have a default backend, too. But this has a different meaning and can be overridden as described here https://www.drupal.org/node/2754947.